# How to get The properties of a Class as a List

Tags: c#, string, collections

I want to get the properties of a class as a string list.

eg:There is a class called `Colors`.Colors has several properties `Colors.RED`,`Colors.Blue` etc
 What i want is to get RED,BLUE etc as a List Is there a way to do that?

**UPDATE:**

This question is not only about Colors class,its just an example

Comment: Please make it more clear by providing example of a class and what you need to extract?

Comment: Is `Colors.RED` really a property of the class `Colors`? Sounds as if it's an enum.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hmm i dont know,just a blind example

Comment: @techno: So do you really want to get the list of all of your class' properties? Why? I'm pretty sure that you can solve what you're actually trying to achieve in a better way. There's no day without people asking for reflection, mostly unexperienced developers. I have almost never needed reflection in 15 years of development. In most cases these questions can be answered with a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Im just a student :),Need time to get experienced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those colors defined in [`KnownColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum. You can easily get its values

```
string[] colors = Enum.GetNames(typeof(KnownColor));
```

UPDATE: Getting public property names with reflection

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static;
var names = typeof(Color).GetProperties(flags).Select(p => p.Name);
```

UPDATE2 It turns out that you want to get default font name constants from [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) [BaseFont](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/BaseFont.cs) class (please, next time specify your intent more detailed). These fonts are stored in protected static field named *BuiltinFonts14*. You can get dictionary with fonts via reflection:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;
var buildinFonts = (Dictionary<string, PdfName>)typeof(BaseFont)
       .GetField("BuiltinFonts14", flags).GetValue(null);
```

And font names are simply keys of this dictionary:

```
var fontNames = buildinFonts.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToArray();
```

Comment: Im not talking about colors,its just an example

Comment: @techno misleading example, I want to say

Comment: So this will work with any classes for example there is a class called ' myclass.bestclass ' so i can use 'var names = typeof(myclass.bestclass).GetProperties(flags).Select(p => p.Name);'

Comment: @techno yes, it works with any class. But be careful with binding flags. With Color you need to select static properties. But with you other class you can set flag to instance. Getting properties without any flags will return both static and instance properties.

Comment: will this work if the values are enum?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43049/discussion-between-lazyberezovsky-and-techno)

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
typeof(Colors).GetProperties()
```

could do the trick.

opps already answered :p